# How do I use cython?

Tags: python, c, cython

I am looking for a simple example of the use of cython.

First, I installed cython via pip in python 3.5.2
Second, I installed the CodeBlocks IDE with minGW compiler. Do I need anything else?

I simply want to convert my Python code to C. How can I do that? Basically I want only a c file to execute with CodeBlocks. I followed the tutorial for hello world: http://docs.cython.org/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html but when I copy paste this:

```
$ python setup.py build_ext --inplace
```

to the command prompt it says that $ is not recognized. I think $ is for Linux and I have windows 10 so I pasted without $ but this did not work either.

I want to execute not like tutorial say but I want simply the C file to run from CodeBlocks if this is possible.

After these I simply executed the `setup.py` from the tutorial by my own which created a helloworld.c file. I tried to run it through CodeBlocks but an error occurred.

So is there a simple way to use cython?

Comment: What is the error you are getting

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve at the end? I don't think that the C code produced by cython is that nice to read (by default).

Comment: The error i'm getting when i run $ python setup.py build_ext --inplace is '$' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file , when i run this without $ i'm getting: python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: When i run the setup.py with Codeblocks i'm getting: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory.The reason i need cython is because i have a very slow algorithm so i want to run it faster in C.

Comment: In my previous comment i meant when i run helloworld.c with Codeblocks not setup.py

Comment: Cannot find `Python.h` well using Cython you are stuck including that header file.  `python setup.py build_ext --inplace` make sure you are in the directory with your `setup.py` file for your helloworld project otherwise you'll get that error.